# Thread Locking In Magento?

Tags: performance, cache, full-page-cache

We just had about 20 httpd processes that were sitting there chewing CPU for over 20 minutes, I am wondering why something like that might happen....

Any ideas are greatly appreciated because I am confused, a quick restart of apache, and the processes never came back.

Comment: If you have EE, there is cron which runs curl crawler to refresh FPC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strace` the processes to get a clue about what they are doing

```
strace -ftttp PID
```

Replace PID with the process ID as necessary.

---

Restating Apache should be a last resort. Those processes could have been callbacks from a payment gateway, customers placing orders etc.

Unless you know it's not genuine load, you shouldn't kill anything.